# How to combine two tables in R with same variables?

Tags: r

New to R.  How to combine these two tables in R so I have two rows and 3 columns:

```
> table8
rchildF
No, not at all rude  Yes, somewhat rude      Yes, very rude 
                114                 284                 286 
> table9
rbabyF
No, not at all rude  Yes, somewhat rude      Yes, very rude 
                473                 148                  63
```

Also how do I convert each value into a percent of the total counted by row (total is 684).

Comment: use `rbind(table8, table9)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `merge`

```
merged <- merge(table8, table9, all = TRUE)
#  No, not at all rude Yes, somewhat rude Yes, very rude
#1                 114                284            286
#2                 473                148             63
```

For percentages use a combination of `round` and `rowSums`

```
percentages <- round(merged/rowSums(merged), 2) * 100
#  No, not at all rude Yes, somewhat rude Yes, very rude
#1                  17                 42             42
#2                  69                 22              9
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr::bind_rows`:

```
library(dplyr)

table8 <- read.table(text = "'No, not at all rude'  'Yes, somewhat rude'      'Yes, very rude' 
114                 284                 286", header = T)

table9 <- read.table(text = "'No, not at all rude'  'Yes, somewhat rude'      'Yes, very rude' 
473                 148                  63", header = T)

bind_rows(table8, table9) %>% 
  transmute(
    not_rude = No..not.at.all.rude/rowSums(.[1:3]),
    some_rude = Yes..somewhat.rude/rowSums(.[1:3]),
    rude = Yes..very.rude/rowSums(.[1:3])
  )

   not_rude some_rude       rude
1 0.1666667 0.4152047 0.41812865
2 0.6915205 0.2163743 0.09210526
```

Comment: This is solution only to a first problem

Comment: Fixed now, with better variable names

Answer (score 0):

R base also does the job. Try

```
# row-binding data frame
df <- rbind.data.frame(table8, table9)

#  No..not.at.all.rude Yes..somewhat.rude Yes..very.rude
#1           0.1666667          0.4152047     0.41812865
#2           0.6915205          0.2163743     0.09210526

# Percentage values
df/rowSums(df)

#  No..not.at.all.rude Yes..somewhat.rude Yes..very.rude
#1           0.1666667          0.4152047     0.41812865
#2           0.6915205          0.2163743     0.09210526

#OR

as.data.frame(apply(df/rowSums(df), 2, scales::percent))
#      No..not.at.all.rude Yes..somewhat.rude Yes..very.rude
#1               16.7%              41.5%          41.8%
#2               69.2%              21.6%           9.2%
```